# How to get only first occurrence in log file using awk

Tags: awk

i've a log file like this

```
some text line
other text line
<a>
  <b>1</b>
  <c>2</c>
</a>
another text line
<a>
  <b>1</b>
  <c>2</c>
</a>
yet another text line
```

I need to get only ther first occurrence of the XML "a":

```
<a>
  <b>1</b>
  <c>2</c>
</a>
```

I know

```
awk '/<a>/,/<\/a>/' file.log
```

will find all occurrences, how can I get just the first? (adding **|head** -n1 obvously doesn't work because it will capture only first line, and I can't know for sure how long "a" is because the awk expression must be generic because I've different log files with different "a" contents)

Comment: This is a good start, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-print-lines-between-two-patterns-inclusive-or-exclusive-in-sed-awk-or just exit after the first match.

Comment: Post valid XML/HTML and use xmlstarlet.

Comment: You should have given the 2 `<a>..</a>` blocks different content so when we're testing a potential solution we can tell if it's the first or 2nd block being output.

Answer (score 0):

This awk:

```
awk '
match($0,/<a>/) {
    $0=substr($0,RSTART)
    flag=1
}
match($0,/<\/a/) {
    $0=substr($0,1,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    print
    exit
}
flag' file
```

can handle these forms:

```
The above awk handles this:
<a><b>1</b><c>2</c></a>
and this:
<a>
  <b>1</b>
  <c>2</c>
</a>
and also <a>
  <b>1</b>
  <c>2</c>
</a> this
the end
```

Another for GNU awk:

```
$ gawk -v RS="</?a>" '
NR==1 { printf RT }
NR==2 { print $0 RT }
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Another slight variation is to simply use a simple counter variable to indicate when you are in the first `<a>...</a>` block, outputting that block and then exiting afterwards. In your case using `n` as the variable to indicate in the first block, e.g.

```
awk -v n=0 '$1=="</a>" {print $1; exit} $1=="<a>" {n=1}; n==1' f.xml
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your input file as `f.xml` you would get:

```
$ awk -v n=0 '$1=="</a>" {print $1; exit} $1=="<a>" {n=1}; n==1' f.xml
<a>
  <b>1</b>
  <c>2</c>
</a>
```

(**note:** the `{n=1}` and `n==1` rules rely on the default operation (`print`) to output the record)

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
$ awk '/<a>/{f=1} f; /<\/a>/{exit}' file
<a>
  <b>1</b>
  <c>2</c>
</a>
```

Last:

```
$ tac file | awk '/<\/a>/{f=1} f; /<a>/{exit}' | tac
<a>
  <b>1</b>
  <c>2</c>
</a>
```

Nth:

```
$ awk -v n=2 '/<a>/{c++} c==n{print; if (/<\/a>/) exit}' file
<a>
  <b>1</b>
  <c>2</c>
</a>
```